# How do we concatenate using blade template engine Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel and don't know if it is possible at all to concatenate a string to a blade variable.

I want to display the name of the author with the `~` sign concatenated to the author's name from the left. Here is my code.

```
<div class="author">~{{ $quote->author or '' }}</div>
```

What I want is if the author is set, it should be displayed with the `~`. 
How do I concatenate this?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

This would be better

```
<div class="author">~{{ isset($quote->author) ? $quote->author : '' }}</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<div class="author">{{ isset($quote->author) ? '~'.$quote->author : '' }}</div>
```

Comment: If you do that the `~` gets displayed regardless whether there is an author or not. What I want is: either the `~` is displayed with the author or nothing is displayed at all

Comment: Your update makes a lot of sense but I wonder why it still doesn't work. Let me update my question a bit. The display is of a record consisting of quote and author. The record was inserted into the database with no author specified. In that case is it right to use  `isset($quote->author)`? Because looking at it closely, i thought `$quote->author` is set to `''` causing ~ to always get displayed with it. What do you think? Sorry for my long comment.

Comment: This is correct brother. I just tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="author">
    @if (isset($quote->author))
     ~ {{ $quote->author }}
    @else 
    @endif
</div>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#control-structures